# How to compile .bat file using QT Creator

Tags: batch, batch-file, compile, qt

Question: How do I compile a .bat file using QT Creator?

More info: specifically, I am trying to install Windows Image Writer and the download only includes source files. The README.txt tells me to use QT Creator (I have just installed this for this purpose alone) to compile the file compile.bat and I have no clue on how to do this.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: QT creator has little to do with .bat files .bat file is an operating system script which you run in cmd.exe or command.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be more than one way to do this:

[Bat2exe](http://www.f2ko.de/programs.php?lang=en&pid=b2e)

This program will take your batch file and compile it.

Lots of options.
I've used it for years when I've been attempting to hide an administrator password, or to keep someone from 'fixing' a script I've written.

Easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

[Is this the software you speak of?](https://launchpad.net/win32-image-writer) If so, you should follow the [README.txt](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~gruemaster/win32-image-writer/0.6/view/head:/README.txt) and just run the `compile.bat` file by double-cliking it or in a shell. You shouldn't even need to open QT Creator yourself at all.

[README.txt](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~gruemaster/win32-image-writer/0.6/view/head:/README.txt):

> ...
>   Build Instructions:
>
> Requirements:
>   1. MinGW
>   2. Qt for Windows SDK
>
> Short Version:
>   1. Install the Qt Full SDK
>   2. Run compile.bat -OR- run qmake and then make in the src folder.
>   3. Compile.bat may be edited to change installation paths of MinGW and QT
>
> ...

#### Edit

Even better, you could download the [binaries](https://launchpad.net/win32-image-writer/+download).